Escaping special characters in password with WinRS
We use WinRS command from various admin scripts to issues commands to remote Windows servers:
winrs /remote:host /username:user /password:pwd command

This is working well except when password pwd contains certain special characters.  I can't quite pinpoint which special characters cause issues. Most of them can be escaped with ^ char (e.g. <, >, ^) and % for %. However even with these escaped, I'm still struggling to get some passwords working. For example, I can't get this password to work: A3={d6*s]bf=<F$s;fg^%3g Can someone provide a definitive list of which special characters needs to be escaped in which way?
Do note that putting the parameter in quotes (single or double) doesn't work, as the quotes are taken to be part of the password.

Does this relate to your case?

BTW, my experience with passwords having special characters and characters with diacritics, particularly for network login, is that they can make it impossible to boot, under certain conditions (e.g., a keyboard layout not available on another PC).

@harrymc no, it doesn't. Your link is about SSH. I'm trying to run a command from a windows server on another remote windows server using WinRS.

I agree with @DrMoishePippik. My experience with special characters in passwords (used by others) is that they're trouble to be avoided. They can't always be escaped.

@harrymc Agree - but I'm working within confines of strict security rules requiring for (non-user uservice) accounts to have complex passwords of 32 chars with the predefined set of upper/lower/digits/special characters.

I never used winrs and the documentation is silent about this question. I saw this answer (which someone even upvoted) that seems to say that quoting is not necessary even for blanks, as long as no positional arguments are used. So one can use the normal CMD/PowerShell escape characters. No idea if it's correct or not.
